# Where does *.i file and how to open it?

Tags: c++

For C/C++ compiler, after preprocessing, it will generate a *.i file, where does it locate,
and how to open it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean a `*.o` file? The compiler will generate it wherever your environment settings/makefile tell it to. Why do you want to open it, though? As far as I'm aware it's only useful to the compiler/linker as an intermediate between code and the finished binary.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler suite calls the preprocessor that creates the preprocessed file. This is usually done at a temporary location and probably with a temporary name. When you want the compiler to stop after preprocessing you have to pass an argument to compiler. When you use GCC it the `-E` argument that causes creation of the .i file.

Choose any editor of your choice to open this file.

*Edit*:
The compiler might utilize pipes instead of temporary files (like GCC `-pipe`). If the hosting operation system doesn't support pipes, this will be implemented using temporary files. sigh.

Comment: Also, GCC has option "-pipe", when even temporary files are not used (from help: "Use pipes rather than intermediate files").

Answer (score 1):

Mainly the preprocessed .i files are used when there is a compiler bug. So for that eiher a test case or a preprocessed .i files are used. In those occation where reproducing test cases are not feasible solution it's better to use a preprocessed .i file.

To generate a preprocessed file (.i file), just add "-EP -P" to the compile option, and recompile the original .cpp file.  You can also generate a .i file directly from the "Prepocessor" property in Visual Studio*:

1. Right click the file name, and click properties
2. Click Preprocessor\Generate Preprocessed File\Without Line Numbers (/EP /P)

if you recompile from a command window, the .i file will be created under the current directory.
if you recompile from within the Visual Studio* IDE, the .i file will be created under the directory where the original source file is located.